# Jquery consistent title header text across all pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile site - a one-pager - and I'm having trouble with the text in the header. It's a simple site with only 5 pages that are all divs with data-role=page. When the page loads I use $.get to retrieve a JSON formatted array generated by an external PHP page. The process page uses a url variable to determine which data to retrieve from our db:

```
$.get("ajax/siteInfo.php?id=" + getURLvar( 'id' ), function(siteData){
  sessionStorage.siteTitle = siteData.siteTitle;
}, "json");
```

There's more data than the 1 item but I'm shortening it for simplicity. The JSON array is retrieved successfully and I can see all of the data key-value pairs in my console.

Also want to point out that I have a function that returns the url var when the site page is loaded (/index.html?id=2001):

```
function getURLvar( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

Now, I want to use sessionStorage.siteTitle in each of the 5 pages:

```
<div data-role="header">
  <h1><script>document.write(sessionStorage.siteTitle);</script></h1>
</div>
```

This works the first time the page is loaded but if I change the url var id and reload the page the title remains for the previous page - even though I can see that the correct title has been retrieved from the JSON array. It's as if sessionStorage.siteTitle is cached so the first time I reload with a new url var id it doesn't change - but if I reload again the new title is displayed.

Hopefully that makes sense. I'm pulling my hair out. If anyone has an idea about this - or even an alternate and more appropriate way of having a consistent title in the header of

Answer (score 0):

After initial page load, that bit of javascript is never processed again. It only sets the header once, which it does successfully. Afterwards, you'll have to manually update the h1:

```
$.get("ajax/siteInfo.php?id=" + getURLvar( 'id' ), function(siteData){
    $('div[data-role="header"] h1').html(siteData.siteTitle);
}, "json");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the text when the pageshow even is fired. This event fires when a page is requested and shown to the user. Here I am attaching the event to all pages:

```
$('div[data-role="page"]').live('pageshow', function() {
     // replace header text
     $(this).children('div[data-role="header"] h1').html(sessionStorage.siteTitle);
});
```